# Switch statement with boolean is not working?

Tags: java, boolean, switch-statement

Why is my compiler telling me:

*Incompatible Types:*

Required: **Boolean**

Found: **Int**

under case 0 & case 1

---

For instance:

```
    public void test(boolean isOn){
    switch (isOn){
        case 0:
            if (isOn){
                System.out.println("its on");
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            if (!isOn){
                System.out.println("its off");
            }
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("I don't know!");
    }
```

}

Driver Class:

```
Club me = new Club();
me.test(true);
```

Comment: Your `switch` and `if` are redundant.

Comment: I know its just so I can at least see how it works, I'm only learning this

Comment: Boolean values - `true`, `false`, `FILE_NOT_FOUND`!  In Java, a `boolean` can only have two values - true, and false.  Your default case will never be reached (and most people would likely use an `if` statement).  Now, `Boolean` (note the capital `'B'`) can be `null` (at which point "I don't know" makes sense), but you're not using that here...

Comment: It's Java's 'feature' proving lazy compiler makes programmer write more in my view.

Answer (score 20):

You are switching on `boolean` type, and your cases are using `int` types. But even though you change your cases to have `boolean` types, that wouldn't work. You cannot switch on `boolean` type. And that wouldn't make any sense as using an `if-else` would be easier anyways:

```
if (isOn) {
    System.out.println("its on");
} else {
    System.out.println("its off");
}
```

Note that there is no `"I don't know!"` case here. A `boolean` type can have either `true` or `false` value. This is another reason, why `switch-case` is not for `boolean` type. There is no default case.

You can also condense it to a single statement by using a *conditional expression*:

```
public void test(boolean isOn) {
    System.out.println(isOn ? "its on" : "its off");
}
```

Comment: I did the changes now under `switch (isOn)` its saying Found: Boolean, Required: Char, Byte, short or int

Comment: @someone You can't switch on `boolean` type, but only `int` types, `String`, or `enum` types.

Comment: Switching on `true` is actually more useful that you make it seem. Go uses it all the time https://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/Switch#Missing_expression

Answer (score 8):

¯\*(ツ)*/¯

```
switch (Boolean.hashCode(isOn)) {
    case 1231 -> System.out.println("its on");
    case 1237 -> System.out.println("its off");
}
```

Comment: Bit late to the party, but made me laugh :D

Answer (score 5):

Just convert the boolean to number of 1 and 0.

```
public void test(boolean isOn){
    int trueOrFalse;
    if(isOn == true){
      trueOrFalse = 1;
    }else{
      trueOrFalse = 0;
    }
    switch (trueOrFalse){
        case 1:
            if (isOn){
                System.out.println("its on");
            }
            break;
        case 0:
            if (!isOn){
                System.out.println("its off");
            }
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("I don't know!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`switch (isOn)`: switching `boolean` and want to case with `int` e.g., `case 0`!

According to the [JLS section 14.11](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11): for a  `switch ( Expression ) SwitchBlock`:

> Expression can only be **`char, byte, short, int, Character, Byte,
>   Short, Integer, String, or an enum type`** other wise a **compile-time
>   error** occurs.
>
> According to the specification followings are also must be true:
>
> 1. Every case constant expression associated with a switch statement
>      must be assignable  to the type of the switch Expression.
> 2. No two of the `case` constant expressions associated with a switch
>      statement may have the same value.
> 3. No `switch` label is `null`.
> 4. At most one default label may be associated with the same switch
>      statement

Hence, switch expression can't be float, double or `boolean`. TO answer the question why?: boolean `true false` are meaningful using with `if-else`, e.g., `if(true) then do`.    Floating point numbers (`float`, `double`) are not a good candiadtes for switch as exact comparison is often broken by rounding errors. e.g. `0.11 - 0.1 == 0.01` is false.

Answer (score 3):

In Java, Switch does NOT work with Boolean.

Accepted variable types are :
char,byte,short,int,String,Character,Byte,Short,Integer,enum

Answer (score 2):

As the error clearly states, numbers are not booleans.

You want `true` and `false`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not C++ where 1 and 0 get implicitly converted to/from true and false.  Switching on boolean is also a waste of time even if you could do it; just write a simple if/else statement, or use the `? :` construct.

Answer (score 0):

In Java switch works only with integer literals and those which could be possibly promoted to integer literals such as char.

Moreover in Java boolean type has only two values either true or false. This is unlike the situation in C/C++ where true is any value not equals to zero and false is zero.

Moreover your code is a bit redundant

Comment: As previously stated: Accepted variable types are : char,byte,short,int,String,Character,Byte,Short,Integer,enum. One can not switch off of Boolean or boolean, as how would one define a default case of neither True or False?

Answer (score 0):

You can not use boolean on switch statements. it is no point to use switch when the statement is true or false. it is easy to use if-else.

Answer (score 0):

Imho switch with boolean would make sense if you could use expressions for case checks instead of if else trees or continues in a loop (maybe I'm wrong that it's a benefit), e.g.:

```
class Testomatoe
{
    private final String country;
    private final String sort;
    private final int pricePerKiloEUCent;
    
    public Testomtoe
    (   final String country,
        final String sort,
        final int pricePerKiloEUCent
    )
    {
        this.country = country;
        this.sort = sort;
        this.pricePerKiloEUCent = pricePerKiloEUCent;
    }
    
    //get...
}


List<Testomataoe> offers = ...
String country;
String sort
int price;

for( Testomatoe tom : offers )
{
    country = tom.getCountry();
    sort = tom.getSort();
    price = tom.getPricePerKiloEUCent();
    
    switch( true )
    {
        case price < 100:
            addToQueryQuality( tom );
            break;

        case isUrgent( sort ) && price < 300:
            adddToPriOrder( tom );
            break;

        case !country.equals( "Somewheria" ) && price <= 200:
            addToOrder( tom );
            break;

        case country.equals( "Island" ) && sort.equals( "BlueFrost" ) && price < 600:
            addToAcceptable( tom );
            break;
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Switch case does not support to use Boolean ,long,float,double.
It supports only primitive data types such as char,int,byte ,short and non primitive String data types....

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).